# Handling missing elements in CSS flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, e-commerce

I have a horizontal flex container that lists products horizontally:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-photo"><img src="/url" /></div>
    <div class="product-name">Jeans</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-photo"><img src="/url" /></div>
    <div class="product-name">Blouse</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-photo"><img src="/url" /></div>
    <div class="product-name">Shoes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (simplified):

```
.container {display: flex; justify-content: left;}
.product {width: 100%;}
.product-photo {width: 100%;}
.product-photo > img {width: inherit;}
.product-name {}
```

A situation might arise where a product image is missing, which causes that `product` element to collapse to contain only its title, looking like this:

```
--------  Blouse    --------
|      |            |      |
|      |            |      |
--------            --------
Jeans               Shoes
```

I would like to display a background color on the `product-photo` element to indicate the missing image and keep the flex display consistent, like this:

```
--------  --------  --------
|      |  $$$$$$$$  |      |
|      |  $$$$$$$$  |      |
--------  --------  --------
Jeans     Blouse    Shoes

$ = missing img element but height and background color from parent product-photo element
```

The product image size / aspect ratio is dynamic and I therefore cannot set fixed pixel widths or heights on any elements for calculations. Is there any display flex hack that can help keeps this display intact? CSS grid is not an option due to browser support. Looking for pure CSS solution, no JS.

Comment: try  `.product{display:flex;flex-direction:column} .product_name{margin-top:auto}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif The products need to be displayed horizontally so this doesn't help. Both width and height of image are unknown. Can you clarify your idea?

Comment: try my CSS and see, I am not applying the CSS to the container but to the product

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting thanks. It's giving me about 70% of the height of the image, not full 100%. Not sure why. Will play with this a bit more.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I get a partial height by setting height:100% on .product-photo, but that's it. This is also unlikely to work on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you haven't give any height to your divs. That's why divs are taking the height of their contents. In this situation when you delete the image your div getting smaller to the title size. You can use something like this for this problem. If you put a default image product-image::before it will give you what you want. I hope I could explain it.
I am leaving a codepen link so that you can remove images in src and see what is happening.
https://codepen.io/atesirem/pen/poeZJWX

```
.container {
         display: flex; 
         justify-content: flex-start;
}
.product {
         flex: 1;
         width: 100%;
         max-width:320px;
         height: 320px;
         background-color:red;
  z-index:1;
  
}
.product-photo {
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         position:relative;
         z-index:5;
}
.product-photo::before {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 215px;
         content : "";
         position:absolute;
         top:0;
         left:0;
         background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618469060682-b0487b7425db?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMzEzNDIzNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400');
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: center center;
          z-index: 1;
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          
}
.product-photo > img {
         max-width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         object-fit: containt;
         z-index:5;
         position:relative;
}
.product-name {}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that the height of the image is unknown. Depends on user upload. Therefore any kind of placeholder image won't work because it won't match the size of the other images. It looks like I'll need to do this in JavaScript - detect the needed image height from other images and then apply it to the empty container.